# Exit jquery $.each

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't `return false` exit the `$.each` loop below?

```
var Items = {
    "5340071": {
        "alt": "Sample text"
    },
    "5333539": {
        "alt": "Sample text"
    },
    // Etc.
};

var viewportBottom = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
$.each(Items, function(itemId, objItem) {      
    $("<img src='/img/1503/4/" + itemId + ".jpg?h=150'>").on('load', function() {
        $(document.body).append($(this));
        var imageTop = $(this).offset().top;
        if (imageTop > viewportBottom) {
            console.log('Exit loop'); // Text is printed in console
            return false;             // This should break the $.each loop, but it doesn't
        }
    });
});
```

Please advise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it works in `for` i assumed it works for `$.each` :)

Comment: @guradio: They're completely different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `return false` from the callback to `$.each` in that code. There's a `return false` in the event handler being attached by `on`.

Normally when you have a nested callback you want to have affect an outer loop, you can set a flag and check it in the outer loop; but that it's impossble here, because by the time the handler is called, the `$.each` loop has long-since finished.

If your goal is to append images until you've filled the viewport, you can't use `$.each`, because you don't know when to stop until the images load, which happens asynchronously. That's fine, we can just trigger loading the next one when the previous one finishes.

```
var Items = {
    "5340071": {
        "alt": "Sample text"
    },
    "5333539": {
        "alt": "Sample text"
    },
    // Etc.
};

var viewportBottom = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
var index = 0;
var itemIds = Object.keys(Items);
loadNextImage();
function loadNextImage() {
    // Get this item ID
    var itemId = itemIds[index++];

    // Get the alt text for it
    var alt = Items[itemId].alt;

    // Create the image WITHOUT a src
    var img = $("<img>");

    // Apply the alt text
    if (alt) {
        img.attr("alt", alt);
    }

    // Hook the load handler BEFORE we set src
    img.one('load', function() {
        // Append the image to the body
        img.appendTo(document.body);

        // Do we have more?
        if (index < Items.length) {
            // Do we have room for more?
            var imageTop = img.offset().top;
            if (imageTop <= viewportBottom) {
                // Yes, load the next one
                loadNextImage();
            }
        }
    });

    // Now set the src
    img.attr("src", "/img/1503/4/" + itemId + ".jpg?h=150");
}
```

Also note the bit about `src` above, your previous code had a race condition which could crop up if the image were in cache.

And you weren't using the `alt` text, so I added that above.

Comment: But how to rewrite the code to make it work? I already tried a flag, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Martin: I can't tell you how to make it work, because as far as I can tell, what you're trying to do is impossible. You're trying to make an event in the future (the image load callback) affect the loop in the present. What is the actual goal of that code? To only append as many images as will fit?

Comment: @Martin: If so, I've posted an update that should get you going the right way.

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't seem to fire the 'load' function.
https://www.beta1.nl/lazyload.php

Comment: @Martin: There was a small error at the end, that last line (now fixed) should be `img.attr("src", "/img/1503/4/" + itemId + ".jpg?h=150");`

Comment: Great, it's working now!
One more question if you don't mind: why postpone setting the image src?

Comment: @Martin: Because of the race condition I mentioned. The main UI thread most JS runs on is a single thread, but the browser as a whole is not single-threaded. It's perfectly valid for the main UI thread to create an image and between that line and the next attaching the `load` handler have a worker thread in the browser to go off, find that image in cache and load it, then look at the img element's list of event handlers, not see anything there, and not queue load handler callbacks. So by the time we've added our `load` handler, the event has already happened. I have seen that happen. :-)